# how to properly configure error handling in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a basic form that I'm rendering in template using standard "{{ form.name_of_field.errors }} tags. When I try to submit an empty form, I expect to see the form re-rendered with "•field is required" next to the empty form fields. What I get instead is a Value Error. "The view wedbpjr.wedb.views.display_prdInboxEntry didn't return an HttpResponse object." Where am I going wrong?

```
<form action="." method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    <table id="inbox_table">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6">
                <div class="fieldWrapper">
                {{ form.assigned_by.errors }}
                <label for="id_assigned_by">Assigned by:</label>
                {{ form.assigned_by }}
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="fieldWrapper">
                {{ form.job_number.errors }}
                <label for="id_job_number">job no:</label><br />
                {{ form.job_number }}
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="fieldWrapper">
                {{ form.cell_number.errors }}
                <label for="id_cell_number">cell:</label><br />
                {{ form.cell_number }}
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="fieldWrapper">
                    {{ form.job_name.errors }}
                    <label for="id_job_name">job name:</label><br />
                    {{ form.job_name }}
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="fieldWrapper">
                    {{ form.request.errors }}
                    <label for="id_request">request:</label><br />
                    {{ form.request }}
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="fieldWrapper">
                    {{ form.note.errors }}
                    <label for="id_note">note:</label><br />
                    {{ form.note }}
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="container">
                      <!--  <div class='well'> -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                                    {{ form.date_due.errors }}
                                    <label for="id_date_due">date_due:</label>
                                    {{ form.date_due}}
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <!--    </div> -->
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            $(function () {
                                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
                            });
                        </script>
                 </div>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="fieldWrapper">
                    {{ form.box.errors }}
                    <label for="id_box">inbox:</label><br />
                    {{ form.box }}
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="fieldWrapper">
                    {{ form.assigned_to.errors }}
                    <label for="assigned_to">assigned_to:</label><br />
                    {{ form.assigned_to }}
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="fieldWrapper">
                    {{ form.basecamp_link.errors }}
                    <label for="id_basecamp_link">basecamp:</label><br />
                    {{ form.basecamp_link }}
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="accepted_by">
                    {{ form.accepted_by.errors }}
                    <label for="id_accepted_by">accepted_by:</label><br />
                    {{ form.accepted_by }}
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="fieldWrapper">
                    {{ form.status.errors }}
                    <label for="id_status">status:</label><br />
                    {{ form.status }}
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="container">
                      <!--  <div class='well'> -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
                                    {{ form.completed_on.errors }}
                                    <label for="id_completed_on">completed:</label>
                                    {{ form.completed_on}}
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <!--    </div> -->
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            $(function () {
                                $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker();
                            });
                        </script>
                 </div>
              </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>
                <p><input id="inbox_submit_btn" type="submit" value="add" /></p>
             </td>
             <td>
                <p><input id="inbox_delete_btn" name="delete" type="submit" value="delete" /></p>
             </td>

          </tr> 
      </table>

</form>
```

Running Django 1.5.1 - Python 2.7

views.py

```
def display_prdInboxEntry(request, id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PrdInboxForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/production-display/'+ id +'/')
    else:
        form = PrdInboxForm()
        user = request.user
        u = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=id)
        creativerecords = InboxEntry.objects.filter(box="Creative")
        studiorecords = InboxEntry.objects.filter(box="Studio")
        records = InboxEntry.objects.filter(assigned_to=u)
        return render_to_response('home_inbox.html', {'form': form, 'records': records, 'studiorecords': studiorecords, 'creativerecords': creativerecords, 'user': user}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors is coming from your view, Make sure you have a condition for your `form.is_valid` equaling `False`.  This usually involves reshowing the form with the incorrect data

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        # ContactForm was defined in the the previous section
        form = ContactForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            # ...
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') # Redirect after POST
    else:
        form = ContactForm() # An unbound form

    return render(request, 'contact.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

The django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view), clearly explains this

Comment: I think my view conforms to this (posted above). Am checking to find how I've misconfigured it.

Comment: @kjarsenal your view has no condition for a post request and an invalid form